# Create clusters using correlation matrix in Python

Tags: python, matrix, block, correlation

all, I have a correlation matrix of 21 industry sectors.  Now I want to split these 21 sectors into 4 or 5 groups, with sectors of similar behaviors grouped together.

Can experts shed me some lights on how to do this in Python please?  Thanks much in advance!

Comment: you can use machine learning clustering methods.

Comment: take a look at scipy.

Comment: sklearn has plenty of [clustering algorithms](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html), this forum is more aimed at specific coding problems than general "How do I" questions

Comment: Thanks much, seralouk and Hielka.  Could either of you give me a simple example on how to get started pls?  I'm not good enough at Python yet.

Comment: Got you, Anderson.  I will take a look at your link.  Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You might explore the use of Pandas [`DataFrame.corr`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html) and the [`scipy.cluster`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/cluster.hierarchy.html#module-scipy.cluster.hierarchy) Hierarchical Clustering package

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as spc


df = pd.DataFrame(my_data)
corr = df.corr().values

pdist = spc.distance.pdist(corr)
linkage = spc.linkage(pdist, method='complete')
idx = spc.fcluster(linkage, 0.5 * pdist.max(), 'distance')
```

Comment: Thanks, Wes.  I got the correlation matrix in Python,  stuck now on how to cluster them into 4 or 5 blocks based upon their correlations.

Comment: Great, Wes.  This is very helpful.  I will start with this. Have a nice weekend!

Comment: Here is a link to an example use of scipy and pandas that may be of interest: https://github.com/TheLoneNut/CorrelationMatrixClustering/blob/master/CorrelationMatrixClustering.ipynb

Comment: What do I do with `idx` once I've obtained it?

Comment: Is this right? Surely if a correlation is 0, then the pairwise distance is 0, which is the opposite of what we want?

Comment: I don't understand the logic behind `pdist(corr)`. Shouldn't `1-corr` be the distance, not Euclidean distance between two rows?

Comment: Can you explain the  0.5 * pdist.max() please?

Comment: @jf328 Is right I believe: The pdist computes pairwise distance between "observations". However, all observations have already been summarized into the correlation matrix (which is exactly pairwise in nature).

Comment: Regarding comment "I don't understand the logic behind pdist(corr). Shouldn't 1-corr be the distance, not Euclidean distance between two rows?":

pdist(corr) and pdist(1-corr) are the same thing.  Negating a matrix doesn't change the pairwise distances, nor does adding a constant offset.

Comment: I'd like to repeat @tillKadabra's question: why 0.5 * pdist.max()? Why not 0.4 or 0.8? (Generally it's helpful to avoid "magic numbers" and instead use named variables and comments to make the rationales clear.) Would love to hear your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, @Wes' answer was suggesting to use some good functions for the task, however he used them incorrectly. After some more reading of the documentation, it seems you need a ***condensed* pairwise distance matrix** before passing it to the [`spc.linkage`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage.html) function, which is the upper-triangular part of the distance matrix, row by row.

It also says that the `spc.pdist` function returns a distance matrix in that condensed form. However, the input is **NOT** a correlation matrix or anything like that. It needs *observations* and will turn them into the matrix itself given the specified metric.

Now, it will come to no surprise to you that a covariance or correlation matrix already summarizes observations into a matrix. Instead of representing a distance, it represents correlation. Here is where I am unsure of what is mathematically the most sound thing to do, but I believe you could turn this correlation matrix into a distance matrix of some sort by just calculating `1.0 - corr`.

So let's do that:

```py
pdist_uncondensed = 1.0 - corr
pdist_condensed = np.concatenate([row[i+1:] for i, row in enumerate(pdist_uncondensed)])
linkage = spc.linkage(pdist_condensed, method='complete')
idx = spc.fcluster(linkage, 0.5 * pdist_condensed.max(), 'distance')
```